# Send JMeter Request to an IP Address with a Fake Host Name

Tags: jmeter

I have a web application that runs under multiple host names, serving customised content depending on the host name, for example:

1. news-site.com serves news from the application
2. music-site.com serves music from the application
3. sport-site.com serves sport results from the application

(And so on, for example with 3,000 separate sites).

I have a test instance of the application and data, and while I could update all of the host names in test, I wondered if the following were possible:

1. Send all traffic to the ip address of the test application
2. Fake the host name in JMeter to test the different content sets

A native JMeter solution would be ideal. If I have to edit host files on the machine or use a proxy, I'd probably prefer to update the test data.

Comment: ip & ports are same and the application can be accessed using    different domain names?

Comment: @vins yes - the application itself handles the different domain names.

Comment: do you mean you have exactly the same scenario for all those "sites"? or do you have different scenarios in JMeter for each of them? Also which component makes a decision which content to serve, based on host name? I.e. if you access the actual host name (instead of its aliases), or IP, how would it redirect you to the proper content?

Comment: @KirilS. yes, the same scenario for all the sites, so the "Latest" page is different for all the websites, with different content - but served from the same application, at the same relative path - but a different host name. i.e. `news-site.com/latest` and `sports-site.com/latest`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is hitting common APIs for all of the sites, you can parameterize your host name.

In your `HTTP Request Sampler`, set your `Server Name or IP` to a variable, eg `${server_name}`. Make sure you keep the path, eg, `/latest`.

Add a `CSV Data Set Config` with each line being a different site, eg, news-site.com.

In your `Thread Group` set either `Loop Count` or `Number of Threads` to be as many times as you have different sites. Each thread will pull a different line in the CSV, giving you all of the sites.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but this would send the request with the real host name. I need to set the IP address, and fake the host name (i.e. the equivalent of setting up entries in a hosts file).